# Macro to tag generated files

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro in an Excel file to create and save to a specific folder another Excel file.
Is there any way to tag the generated file, so that the tag are visible in Windows Explorer while browsing the folder where the files are saved?

Comment: You could add a comment easily enough which could be seen in explorer, are you stuck to using tags?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Where the "tags" information is displayed in windows explorer - you can also display "comments". It's easy to add these comments to the file using VBA but extremely difficult to add tags as these can only be added to a closed file and there's no native support in VBA to do this easily.

Comment: that will do, too. I am looking for a way to make life easier for the users, when searching their file into the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BuiltInDocumentProperties` collection to add a comment which can also be searched for in windows explorer:

```
'// workbook must be open
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("My Workbook.xlsx")

'// add a comment to the workbook
targetWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Comments").Value = "my comment"

'// save the workbook
targetWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Workbooks\My Saved Workbook.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

The workbook will now have a comment of "my comment" which can be searched for in windows explorer.